# Zend Framework: Looking For a Basic "stub" for a project

Tags: php, zend-framework

We've got a lot of ZF experience.

Current project needs a basic user "control panel" and a staff "control panel" backend.

We could roll this from scratch, but it seems like a waste of time. What we'd like:

1. User Management (registration, forgot password, remember me, etc)
2. ACL & Authentication
3. A simple "backend control panel" for those features
4. Any other "commodity" feature

We looked at Wordpress as an option. And Pimcore. But really, I'd love something simple. Just basic to save a week of boring work.

Answer (score 4):

[Digitalus](http://digitaluscms.com/) is a Zend Framework CMS, otherwise you could roll your own, and use it for future projects.

Comment: Of course we can write it ourselves... but I'd much rather leverage the investment of others. We can devote our resources to adding the features that aren't just commodity code. But thanks anyway guys. Digitalus, like pimcore and tomatocms, are just too complex for what we're seeking.